# Unable to update ViewController from UIAlertController inside ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, ios12

I'm trying to create (just for learning ios) a simple quiz. The game consist of 13 questions. User can answer with two buttons one for true and another for false. On each answer a progress bar advance, score and answer are updated. After 13th answer an alert inform the user he reached last question and the only available choice allow to restart the game.

Without UIAlertController the restart mechanism works perfectly. And also with UIAlertController using breakpoint every variable seems to be updated correctly, but the UI is not updated at all. Another strange thing is that UI is not updated until the user tap on an answer. While pressing (before release) on an answer button update are applied and when the button is released the game jump to the second answer. Then everything works until the UIAlert is shown again.

Please take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/longilineo/quizzler)

Here is a gif with issue occurring: [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tANjo.jpg). As you can see after click on 'Restart' the UI is not updated until I tap on a button. And after tap the app show immediatly the second question. The first question is shown only while the button is pressed.

Tryied on latest xcode version for ios 12.1 iphone 8 on mojave.

Comment: I tried your app by building with Xcode 10.1 and running on an iPhone 8 simulator (iOS 12.1).  I don't see the problem you described.

Comment: I agree with @PhillipMills. all UI updated when alert will dismiss

Comment: tryied on two different mac and have the same problem, ios 12.1, iphone 8 simulator, xcode 10b and 10.1